# Week picker with Ui-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/7RMrNOGrdVVIuVFDM49T?p=preview) week picker, and it is working fine, but i want
       little more to be done with this, like when i select a week, all the
       dates in between range should be selected and background color should
       be set to the dates in range. is it possible to do this.

**Date Picker**

```
<input ng-model="formData.dueDate" type="button" id="dueDate" name="dueDate" class="form-control" datepicker-options="dateOptions" datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" datepicker-append-to-body="true" is-open="true" min-mode="week" datepicker-mode="day"  show-button-bar="false" ng-click="data.isOpen = true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define a class for some days.

So with the date selected you can select a period:

```
$scope.classForWeek = function(date, mode) {
        if (mode === 'day') {
          var start = moment($scope.formData.dueDate).startOf('isoWeek').toDate();
          var end= moment(start).add(1, 'week');
          if (start<= date && end> date) {
            return 'weekClass';
          }
        }
        return '';
      };
```

And the html:

```
<input ng-model="formData.dueDate" type="button" id="dueDate" name="dueDate" class="form-control" datepicker-options="dateOptions" datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" datepicker-append-to-body="true" is-open="true" min-mode="week" datepicker-mode="day"  show-button-bar="false" ng-click="data.isOpen = true" custom-class="classForWeek(date,mode)" />
```

Pluncker example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/rV6m1c8ovXONtHJjtp2Z?p=preview

Comment: but this function is not getting called, can you please update the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/oI1uhS81XuUWS7Yp7WZ7?p=preview

Comment: not working, consider updating plunker, would be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use this on data-ng-change

> $('.active').closest('tr').find('button').addClass('active');

Comment: thank you for you response, it is not working with angular data-change-function but working only once in plain jquery